# Plugin de chatbot externo me desactiva HTTPS

Tags: https

Instalé el plugin de chat de hubspot.com en mi sitio y cuando está activo me deshabilita el SSL en el sitio. Al abrir la web por primera vez carga el SSL y el chat correctamente, pero si actualizo o abro la pagina nuevamente ya no carga el SSL. Si fuerzo al sitio mediante htaccess a cargar con HTTPS, el plugin chat no carga.

Leí en algun sitio que tengo que establecer al complemento externo como un sitio de confianza, pero como hago eso?

El sitio es: http://1tiendaonline.com/

Gracias!

Comment: Existen muchas variables, pero este link puede darte una idea: https://www.siteground.com/kb/install_certificate_ordered_from_another_provider/

Comment: Hola, gracias por su respuesta. Al final lo pude solucionar, volví a cargar el plugin y funciono sin problemas (era tan simple que no lo consideré). Tenés idea si se puede cancelar la recompensa?

Comment: la verdad es que lo desconozco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al final lo pude solucionar, volví a cargar el plugin y funciono sin problemas (era tan simple que no lo consideré).
PD: quiero eliminar el post pero debido a que puse recompensa no me deja... mis disculpas.

Comment: Pues, no deberías, al contrario, déjalo libre, la pregunta ha sido vista 57 veces desde que la publicaste, seguro que a alguien le será de utilidad :)